# Fill an object with an image, not with color (paint image to a canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

I'm creating a Javascript Game and was wondering if anyone could help me with the objects. In stead of color to fill the object I would like to have an image which fills the object. How can this be done?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Nielsvangils/1tgo08bb/)

```
var PlayerX;

var canvas = document.getElementById("gamefield");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

PlayerX = new Player();

function Player()
{
    this.width = 30;
    this.height = 50;
    this.x = canvas.width/4;
    this.y = canvas.height/3*2;
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.fillStyle="#00BFFF";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}

function Update () 
{
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    PlayerX.draw();
}
```

Comment: When you say "fill" the object, what do you mean? Including an image is easy, but if you want to start fitting it into shapes it gets more complex.

Comment: @DBS I'm trying to get an image as the player. In my JSFIDDLE example my player is blue. I'm trying to get a png-file in stead of the blue color.

Comment: @Nielsvangils is there any reason why are you using canvas ? and not simple dom elements ? also about your question you wont be filling the rectangle with an image you will simply create another item which is an image at the same size/location of the rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use `context.drawImage` to draw your playerImage instead of a rectangle.**

Note that the image will take time to load so you must create your player inside the `playerImage.onload` callback. You must also start your game loops inside that onload.

```
var PlayerX;

var canvas = document.getElementById("gamefield");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var playerImg=new Image();
playerImg.onload=start;
playerImg.src="putYourImageHere.png";
function start(){
    PlayerX = new Player();
}

function Player()
{
    this.width = 30;
    this.height = 50;
    this.x = canvas.width/4;
    this.y = canvas.height/3*2;
    this.draw = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(PlayerImg,this.x, this.y);
    }
}
```